# Why does "free -h" show less total memory than assigned by splitting?

Tags: memory

I have a static memory splitting (configured in config file and confirmed by `vcgencmd`) of

```
arm=496M
gpu=16M
```

But when I run `free -h` I get

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          485M       184M       300M         0B        17M       128M
-/+ buffers/cache:        38M       446M
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

So, a total of 485 MB instead of 496 MB. Where did the 11 MB go? Also, the sum of columns `used` + `free` is 484 MB instead of 485 MB. How does the memory calculation work? `free` agrees with `cat /proc/meminfo`, as a side note.

**Why are these numbers not matching?**

Comment: 496*1000/1024=484. Different definitions of what is `kilo` is (1000 or 1024).

Answer (score 1):

on my system:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        496948     260252     236696          0       6560     210968
-/+ buffers/cache:      42724     454224
Swap:       102396      21940      80456
$
```

260252 + 236696 = 496948, and you should drop `-h` switch to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: This does it also show for me. 496948 / 1024 = 485MB. So, `free -h` calculates correctly. 496 MB * 1024 should be 507904 kB, however. So, there are still some MB missing.

Comment: there are megabytes of 1024kb size and there are megabytes of 1000kb size, you should not worry this much about it.

Comment: I know about 2-based and 10-based prefixes, but some tools on the Raspberry Pi seem to use/name it not consistently, and now I'd like to know where the "bug" sits and which numbers to trust.